# How to manage empty select results

Tags: json, jq

I have this input JSON

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Amsterdam",
               "short_name" : "Amsterdam",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Government of Amsterdam",
               "short_name" : "Government of Amsterdam",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

If I apply this filter with jq

```
.results[0]|{label:"a",test:(.address_components[].types|select(.[0]| contains("administrative_area_level_2"))|.[1]?)}
```

I have a result

```
{
  "label": "a",
  "test": "political"
}
```

If I modify the filter in (it's an empty selection)

```
.results[0]|{label:"a",test:(.address_components[].types|select(.[0]| contains("administrative_area_level_3"))|.[1]?)}
```

I have a completely [empty result](https://jqplay.org/s/Wdqyvx-ZBS).

How to obtain something like

```
{
  "label": "a",
  "test": ""
}
```

How to manage it with jq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the alternative operator `//`. The expression `E // ""` will produce the empty string if E is empty or `null` or `false`:

```
<file jq '.results[0]|{label:"a",test:((.address_components[].types|select(.[0]| contains("administrative_area_level_3"))|.[1])//"")}'
```

Notice that in the present case you don't need the `?` operator.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

if you're not limited to the jq, may I kindly offer you an alternative tool I recently developed - `jtc`, with that tool your ask would look like (assuming your json is in `file.json`):

```
bash $ echo '{ "label": "a", "test": "" }' | jtc -w'<test>l' -eu jtc -w'<administrative_area_level_2> [-1] [1]' file.json \;  
{
   "label": "a",
   "test": "political"
}
bash $ echo '{ "label": "a", "test": "" }' | jtc -w'<test>l' -eu jtc -w'<administrative_area_level_3> [-1] [1]' file.json \;  
{
   "label": "a",
   "test": ""
}
bash $
```

UPDATE: starting from `jtc` *v.167*, the cli argument (of `-eu`) requires additional quoting, e.g.:

```
bash $ echo '{ "label": "a", "test": "" }' | jtc -w'<test>l' -eu jtc -w"'<administrative_area_level_2> [-1] [1]'" file.json \;
{
   "label": "a",
   "test": "political"
}
bash $
```

PS. you may find `jtc` on github.com, or google up with keywords jtc and json