# jq empty result by select on array

Tags: arrays, json, select, null, jq

given the following JSON :

```
{
  "id": "4",
  "j": [
    {
      "f": 1,
      "d": "x1"
    },
    {
      "f": 2,
      "d": "x2"
    },
    {
      "f": 3,
      "d": "x3"
    }
  ]
}
```

the following query yields an empty result if  selector is changed to a non existent filter value

works as intended:

```
{k:.id,m:.j[] | select(.f==3)|.d}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/E8rS0Mf_so

empty:

```
{k:.id,m:.j[] | select(.f==4)|.d}
```

the result I wanted should be something like:

```
{
  "k": "4",
  "m": null
}
```

the solution proposed in [How to manage empty select results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54361098/how-to-manage-empty-select-results) does not work easily

```
{k:.id,m:(.j[] | select(.f==4)|.d//null)}
```

neither with the questionmark as proposed in documentation next to [alternative](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Alternativeoperator://)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just a matter of parentheses.

With your data, the following modification of your original query produces the result shown below:

```
{k:.id, m: ((.j[] | select(.f==4)|.d) // null)}
```

Result:

```
{"k":"4","m":null}
```

Answer (score 0):

after giving this a good nights sleep, and trying out what the manual has to offer on this the most simple solution I have come up with is

```
{k:.id,m:[.j[] | select(.f==4)|.d][0]}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/Ao8_GuHWI4

I did not read the whole manual, but i guess at some point it will say that it falls upwards by the multiplicity of the partial results or something which would yield more than one result if the select would find more items!

in the given solution this does not prevail only returning 1 result even if the select would match up with more items

however you can come around it by actually doing it right with the alternative operator ;)

```
{k:.id,m:([.j[] | select(.f==4)|.d][]//null)}
```

https://jqplay.org/s/uBG5c969pf